# Customize Badge Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have been searching for a long time for how to customize a badge component like https://mui.com/material-ui/react-badge/.

Currently, this only allows making it as a dot or put a number in a circle inside the badge. But I would like to customize it like changing the shape to a star of something. I don't know what does it called. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [ask], then revise to ask something clear and specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Badge, withStyles } from '@mui/material';

const CustomBadge = withStyles((theme) => ({
  badge: {
    width: '20px',
    height: '20px',
    backgroundColor: '#FFD700', // Custom color (e.g., gold)
    borderRadius: '50%', // Circular badge
    clipPath: 'polygon(50% 0%, 61% 35%, 98% 35%, 68% 57%, 79% 91%, 50% 70%, 21% 91%, 32% 57%, 2% 35%, 39% 35%)', // Custom star shape using clip-path
    transform: 'rotate(-90deg)', // Adjust rotation as needed
  },
}))(Badge);

const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Use the custom badge component */}
      <CustomBadge badgeContent={5} overlap="circular">
        {/* Content that will display the badge */}
        {/* For example, an icon or text */}
        {/* Replace this with your content */}
        <span>Notification Icon</span>
      </CustomBadge>
    </div>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```